# How to pass a `msg` to unittest.mock assert methods?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

The [TestCase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html?highlight=testcase#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) docs specify that assert methods can take an optional `msg` keyword argument to specify a message to add context to the assertion:

> All the assert methods accept a *msg* argument that, if specified, is used as the error message on failure (see also longMessage).

Is there a way to do this with the [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) assert methods, in particular [`assert_any_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_any_call)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L869) of `assert_any_call`, the message is hard-coded:

```
raise AssertionError(
    '%s call not found' % expected_string
) from cause
```

Moreover, the `AssertionError` is raised directly in the code, rather than being the consequence of a failed `assert` statement. This pattern is followed by all the `assert_*` methods in the module.  So there is no way to set a custom message unless you subclass and override the methods that interest you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, bit I think it's still relevant:

You can always just catch and reraise yourself:

```
try:
    my_mock.assert_any_call()
except AssertionError as e:
    raise AssertionError("My custom message") from e
```